# $\mathbb{P}[A]\cdot\mathbb{E}[X|A] = \mathbb{E}\big[X\cdot\mathbf{1}[A]\big]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $A$ denote an event and $X$ denote a random variable. Is it true that
$$\mathbb{P}[A]\cdot\mathbb{E}[X|A] = \mathbb{E}\big[X\cdot\mathbf{1}[A]\big],$$
where $\mathbf{1}[A]$ is an indicator function that event $A$ happens? We assume $\mathbb{P}[A] > 0$.

Comment: Yes, whenever $P(A)>0$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Is this the definition or it comes from others?

Comment: Yes: provided $\mathbb{P}(A)$ does not vanish, by definition, $\mathbb{E}(X|A):=\mathbb{E}(X;A)/\mathbb{P}(A)$ where $\mathbb{E}(X;A):=\mathbb{E}(X \mathbb{1}_A)$

Comment: @StubbornAtom When $P(A) = 0$, aren't both sides guaranteed to be $0$, meaning the equation is true whether $P(A) > 0$ or not?

Comment: @TannerSwett I suppose you can say that, but the issue is that $E[X \mid A]$ is not well-defined if $P(A) = 0$.

Comment: @angryavian Ah, got it. I thought that conditional expected value was sometimes defined if $P(A) = 0$, but in researching that idea, I read about the [Borel–Kolmogorov paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox), explaining why it's not defined. Very interesting!

Comment: Whether your identity holds or not depends on your precise interpretation of conditional probability. In my book, we would have $E[X|A] = 1[A] E[X 1[A]]/P(A)$, so that in your identity you would be missing a factor $1[A]$ on the right hand side...